# Can't add anything to Cloud Firestore from console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've searched all the internet, but found no similar resolved issues.

So, I'm playing around with Cloud Firestore and my issue is simply that I can't add anything to Firestore from console, I click on "Add collection", enter name, then generate random id for new document, and add a single string to it. After clicking "Save", nothing is added and screen still says "No data at this location yet". I tried reloading, logging off and in again, adding only empty collection, etc. Anyone knows what could be wrong? Maybe that's some bug because Firestore is in beta?

Comment: Perhaps there is something malformed in the collection id or field name that we aren't handling errors correctly. SO isn't the best place for debugging things like this, I'd suggest posting to the discussion group at groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: You could also contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Whichever one of the two suggestions you do: be sure to include 1) any relevant messages that show up in the JavaScript console of your browser 2) if possible a short screen capture of when you enter the data.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the similar issue, after a lot of research, I found out that there is an issue with chrome browser. Just open the same console with firefox browser, you will be able to do all the operations :)

Answer (score 1):

Following Xavi's advice, I found out that it worked on Safari, I then went back to the Chrome Firebase console and logged out of all accounts and re-logged in with the account I have Firebase access to, and I am now able to read and write from the console and also from my React app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to go to the collection that you have created directly via parent path.

EDIT:
Sorry, I was wrong. Problem still occurs. Found out antivirus blocks these operations. I'm using kaspersky

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here. It works after I enable data collection on Kaspersky.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no document in the collection, the collection disappears. The process is fairly fail-proof. You can enter 1 as the document name and 1 as the string field leaving the value blank and it will still write.

Try adding a different data type. Also, try and use one of the SDKs, the web (browser) or admin (Node.js) SDK to write (`.set`) data in a document `firebase.firestore().collection("test").doc().set({"name":"john"});` with the test/open security rules in place.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:

Firebase does not accept undefined values by default.
Check your values: Having undefined values could well be the reason.